# What font is this possible Garamond variation?

Tags: font-identification, serif

This is a font I found in a church building. It's a typed out message, so I know the font exists. It might be Garamond Schoolbook, but I can't find it anywhere. It seems the italic versions of Garamond and variations have an open 'a' but I can't find the equivalent in a regular weight.

[image: Sample]

[image: Sample2]

Comment: The single-storey ɑ and ɡ are almost certainly alternate glyphs; but even so, I can’t find a single version of Garamond on MyFonts that has any such alternate glyphs and looks even remotely like this one.

Comment: It seems really bizarre to me, because it seems that if it's a font, then it exists somewhere... but like you said it doesn't seem to exist...

Answer (score 2):

You are correct that the typeface in question is a schoolbook variety of Garamond. More specifically, [EB Garamond](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/EB+Garamond?selection.family=EB%20Garamond) utilizing the alternate characters for the lowercase `a` and `g`.

***Note:*** The only noticeable difference with EB Garamond and your sample is the extremity of the curves on some of the lower case letter serifs (see `n` and `i` for example) but EB Garamond is close and available as a Google Font. Based on the serifs, my guess is this is more closely related to [Simoncini Garamond](https://www.linotype.com/1476/simoncini-garamond-family.html) but I wasn't able to verify if it includes the alternate schoolbook characters in the font package.

You can access these alternate letters by using the **Glyphs Panel** (`Window > Glyphs` in Photoshop or `Window > Type > Glyphs` in Illustrator). Simply select the letter you'd like to replace, find the appropriate alternate in the **Glyphs Panel** and double-click it to replace:

[image]
*^ This sample only replaces the `a` but where the `g` "lives" for EB Garamond is highlighted*

---

### [EB Garamond on Google fonts](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/EB+Garamond?selection.family=EB%20Garamond)

Comment: Wow... PS finally has a glyphs panel! (nice find btw)

Comment: Hey, thanks bunches! I should have realized that a font as popular as Garamond would have alternate glyphs like that. I personally use fontforge, and I switched that glyphs that way, so thanks for finding that!

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is a "schoolbook" variant of Garamond - quite a loose redraw, though. EB Garamond will be close enough, I think. [Andron ABC](http://www.myfonts.com/fonts/andreas-stotzner/andron-2-abc/) has these characters moved up to defaults if the program you want to use can't handle alternates.